# Can't run Exchange 2013 EMS installed during 2003-2013 migration

Tags: windows-server-2012, exchange-2007, exchange-2013, exchange-migration

We are migrating a client from Exchange2003 to Exchage2013 (via 2007).

We have migrated succesfully from the SBS2011 to a staging server with Windows 2008 R2 & Exchange2007, however on the Windows 2012 server (on which we have installed Exchange 2013 without errors), when we run the Exchange EMS we get the error below (server.domain.local has replaced the real FQDN).

Neither can we login to the ECP as the administrator credentials are not accepted.

**Exchange 2013 EMS error:-**

```
VERBOSE: Connecting to server.domain.local
New-PSSession: [server.domain.local] Connecting to remote server server.domain.local failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSSession -Connection URI "$connectionUri" -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Excha ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo             : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotein
  gTransportException
  + FullQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

This repeats four times and then prompts with:

```
Failed to connect to an Exchange server in the current site.
Enter the server FQDN where you want to connect.:
```

We have rebuild the ECP and OWA folders, Service packed to the hilt, checked time-sync and AD sync, checked DNS and DHCP are all correct, disabled all but one NIC, and the EMS for Exchange 2007 works fine... But can't find any pointers on where else to look.

I've also run the EMTshooter as recommended by Joe, and although it confirms the error it classes it as an 'Unknown Error'

```
...
         Location ConnectToAnyServer 2
VERBOSE: Connecting to SERVER.domain.local

new-pssession : [server.domain.local] Connecting to remote server server.domain.local failed with the 
following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At D:\tools\EMTshooter\EMTConnectFunctions.ps1:177 char:15
+             $session = new-pssession -connectionURI "http://$fqdn/powershell?serializatio ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin 
   gTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
The Exchange Management Troubleshooter successfully completed connecting to:

server.domain.local

Failed to connect to any Exchange Server in the current site.

Problem found:

Looking for error...

Unknown Error

After each error is resolved, close this window and re-run the tool to check for additional problems.
```

Can anyone provide any pointers?

TIA

Comment: Please try to run the EMTshooter first: Resolving WinRM errors and Exchange 2010 Management tools startup failures http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/12/07/3411644.aspx

Comment: Thanks Joe, have done so, but it just declares it an 'Unknown Error' - so still no further forwards :( (Have updated description above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if your running Essentials....

If you are running Windows 2012 Server Essentials then Exchange 2013 isn't supported.

Likewise if you are running Windows 2012 Server Standard with Essentials Role Added then Exchange 2013 isn't supported.  The pre-req check doesn't report Essentials Role as a problem on the install but it isn't supported.

If you have got this far, you will need to uninstall Exchange 2013 and then remove the Essentials Role before reinstalling Exchange 2013.  On some cases you may have to reinstall the server complete because I have had problems removing the Essentials Role after its been installed.

Note you will have to move/remove the Discovery Mailbox and Arbitration Mailbox which are created in the Exchange 2013 install in order to uninstall the Exchange 2013 server.  This article explains well the process http://msexchangeguru.com/2013/01/02/exchange-2013-error/

During the uninstall you will need to run some EMS CmdLets, As your EMS isn't working then run the normal PowerShell as Administrator and then run the following `Add-PSSnapin *exch*`. This will give you access to the Exchange CmdLets from within the PowerShell.